# Battery labeling

Tags: batteries

I hope EE.SE is correct, otherwise, please point me to the right SE

---

According to IEC 61960 chapter 5 cells must be labeled like:

A1A2A3N2/N3/N4

e.g.
ICR19/66

Yet, this information is hardly found on any cell in the market. Every big company only provides 18650 with some additional information.

Why is that so?

What are the legal impacts of this missing label in case of a hazard?

Comment: I don't think it says anywhere that they need to be marked that way, just that this is a way to name them

Comment: IEC 61960 says: "Cells must be labeled as follows"

Comment: since afaik the document is not readable free of charge for everyone, you might want to quote from the section (and tell which version of the standard you refer to). The last time I read it (many years ago) there was a distinction between label/designation and actual required markings on the battery itself

Comment: The publication is only a year old. Furthermore, is it a mandatory standard? It could be that it's not required (or that it is not known that i's required) by the various markets.

Comment: Legal impacts would depend on jurisdiction, and in many jurisdictions a proprietary (non-free) standard couldn't be law. There's a widespread rejection of secret laws.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IEC standard may say something about labeling, but the part you're missing is that there is not necessarily anything that forces companies to follow the IEC standard.

Companies don't follow standards like this unless they have to.  "Have to" comes from two places, government regulations and market requirements.  If the government doesn't require it, and the customers don't care, then there is no reason for companies to go thru the expense of being certified to a particular standard.

For example, large retailers here in the US often won't carry electrical products that aren't certified to certain safety standards (shock hazard, fire, etc).  As a result, companies that want to sell their gizmos into that market effectively have to get them certified to those standards.

On the other hand, if nobody cares or forces you to do it, there is little point in going thru the hassle and expense of certification.

Some standards are also silly or over-bearing, and end up being ignored.  There is no point jumping onto a standard until it is widely accepted.  Only time can tell that.